# Drawing path by Bezier curves

Tags: iphone, graphics, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, bezier

I have a task - draw smooth curve

**input:** set of points (they added in realtime)

**current solution:** I use each 4 points to draw qubic Bezier curve (1 - strart, 2 and 3rd - control points, 4- end). End point of each curve is start point for the next one.

**problem:** at the curves connection I often have "fracture" (angle)

Can you tell me, how to connect my points more smooth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is few references which can help you:

> - [Draw a Smooth Curve through a Set of 2D Points with Bezier Primitives](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx)
> - [Curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)
> - [Line Smoothing and point-weeding](http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/output/html/GeometricandRelatedOperations.html#_Toc294790379)

Comment: The third reference is dead. (``Line Smoothing and point-weeding``)