# How to smooth marker stroke for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, drawing, marker

Hi I am working on an application where i have to draw something. When I draw with marker stroke it makes some edges, how i can avoid these edges?
[image]

[image]

Code for marker stroke

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//    KidsPhotoBookAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KidsPhotoBookAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
//    brushPattern = (UIColor*)appDelegate.kidsSelectedColor;

    DBManager *dbMgr = [DBManager sharedManager];
    [dbMgr.c setStroke];
    for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
        [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];  
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    KidsPhotoBookAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KidsPhotoBookAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineWidth = appDelegate.kidsBrushSize;
    myPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    brushPattern=appDelegate.kidsSelectedColor;
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [pathArray addObject:myPath];

    appDelegate.viewContainsDrawing = YES;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076622/iphone-smooth-sketch-drawing-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this smoothness with the help of this code https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View

Answer (score 4):

You should set line join to [kCGLineJoinRound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCGLineJoinRound) using [CGContextSetLineJoin](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextSetLineJoin) function. See the [Quartz 2D Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-CJBEIHHJ) for more.

**UPDATE**

Since you are using `UIBezierPath`, you should try setting the `lineJoinStyle` of `UIBezierPath` to `kCGLineJoinRound`.

Answer (score 1):

How are you drawing those curves? If you're drawing a sequence of short straight line segments, that's the problem. You should be drawing these sorts of curves with a bezier path. If you're using a bezier path already, you may need to tweak the `flatness` property.