# Improving Drawing Performance (for Dudel application)

Tags: ios, performance, drawing, quartz-graphics, drawrect

I needed to create a small drawing/paint application, so i turned to [Beginning IPad Development for IPhone Developers: Mastering the IPad SDK By Jack Nutting, Dave Wooldridge, David Mark](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=mTGLGxnth0YC&lpg=PA194&ots=S85R4fAt2b&dq=Dudel%20Drawing%20Performance&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false).

It's pretty nice. The architecture is strong. But, the drawing application (**Dudel**) is not very good in terms of performance. There are two main issues (for me, at the moment):

1. Most Important: The drawing slows down after a while. Reason: `drawRect` is being called, every time, for all the paths.
2. The drawing with Pencil tool isn't smooth. Reason: It's using `addLineToPoint:` instead of (may be) `addQuadCurveToPoint:`.
3. There's no Eraser control. But it's really not an issue, because we can choose white color for the painting go give an illusion of an eraser. But, if there's a better implementation for that, i'm interested to know.

**Question:**

Is there a solution out there that addresses these issues, and provide a simple but efficient drawing application?

Note: I need the Undo/Redo feature as well.

Comment: Did u find a solution to for your Point 1?

Comment: I managed to improve the performance, but at some additional cost. I don't redraw every time a new path is added. Instead I draw over an already captured image of the previously drawn image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question one by one.

> The drawing with Pencil tool isn't smooth. Reason: It's using addLineToPoint: instead of (may be) addQuadCurveToPoint:.

What you say is true.IOS device looks for touches in a defined interval. If you move your hand fast, it is very likely that you may end up losing few touch points . Hence connecting points using lines results in ugly spikes.

We can smooth the curve by [curve fitting](http://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=curve%20fitting&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=EdCCT73qA4jlrAft4eTnBQ) algorithms.However Some tweaks in the drawing can result in measurable improvement in quality. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501354/641062) is an example for it.

> Eraser control

If you know the background color you can use that as brush color to give an eraser feeling. if you do not know the background you can use

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
```

> Undo/Redo

you can use [NSUndoManager](http://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=NSUndoManager&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=q8-CT9CtGpGrrAfag43zBQ) .