# objective-c moving touch too fast

Tags: objective-c, multi-touch

I am doing drawing app and I have following problem.
I have an array of points that should be drawn on screen. 
in 
`(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` I add touched point in array and redraw view. But the problem is when I move finger too fast points are not added continiously:

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone smooth sketch drawing algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076622/iphone-smooth-sketch-drawing-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a CGPoint for last touch and one for current touch, then calculate the distance. If the distance is to far (meaning that the user moved to fast), draw dots in between them.