# Draw Bezier Curve with Touch points like Flight control app

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

i am Developing new application like flight control in ios App.in that i need to draw bezier curve with touch and touch move, like same in flight control app.for what i am collecting all the touch points in array and we have to pass to Bezier. is that the right process?, and how can we delete un neccessary points from array.can nows which is the best way to move our ccsprite object along with touch points like flight control app,if any tutorials are sample code will help me a lot.Thank you.

Comment: A good place to look may be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076622/iphone-smooth-sketch-drawing-algorithm