# Draw smooth Bezier curve with cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

It may be a duplicate with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076622/iphone-smooth-sketch-drawing-algorithm),
but I don't know how to apply this approach in my app, and which method I should use in cocos2d-x to draw a Bezier curve. My app should allow users to draw lines and curves when they touch the canvas. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CCDrawPrimitives.cpp file.

You can use this method.

ccDrawCubicBezier
ccDrawQuadBezier

```
-MyClass::draw() {
    glLineWidth(4.0f);
    ccPointSize(4);

    //Draw a blue quadratic bezier curve
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 0, 255, 255);
    ccDrawQuadBezier(ccp(90,0), ccp(200, 70), ccp(350,0), 12);

    //Draw cubic red bezier curve
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
    ccDrawCubicBezier(ccp(100,100), ccp(300,150), ccp(250,50), ccp(350,100), 12);

    //Restore original values
    glLineWidth(1);
    ccDrawColor4B(255,255,255,255);
    ccPointSize(1);
}
```

Every time you move your touch positions, ccTouchesMoved method is called as you may know. 
You can control the curve shape using the method and member variables.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any option for passing an point array to this method? Because I need to store and redraw curve by point array. Another one, I see this warning in document http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.3/d6/da4/group__global.html : `Warning
This function could be pretty slow. Use it only for debugging purposes.` Do I need to worry about this warning?

Comment: Please check the function 'ccDrawQuadBezier' in CCDdrawprimitives.cpp.    All details is in there. Copy and make your version. And glDrawArrays function is not so bad performance I think. Profile it if you doubt.

Answer (score 5):

From Cocos2dx v3.3 you can use DrawNode to draw Bezier curves. Check the DrawPrimitivesTest.cpp, it is very easy to use.
This is only a sample script taken from the above mentioned file. You can use it anywhere in your Scene:

```
auto draw = DrawNode::create();
addChild(draw, 10);

auto s = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
draw->drawQuadBezier(Vec2(0, s.height), Vec2(s.width/2, s.height/2), Vec2(s.width, s.height), 50, Color4F(CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), 0.5));  
draw->drawCubicBezier(VisibleRect::center(), Vec2(VisibleRect::center().x+30,VisibleRect::center().y+50), Vec2(VisibleRect::center().x+60,VisibleRect::center().y-50),VisibleRect::right(),100, Color4F(CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), CCRANDOM_0_1(), 0.5));
```